# is there a way to run a mySQL query to fetch two rows which having same foreign key?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get this SQL query but apparently no able to crack this. I want to have the records where it fetched with the (FK) quoteid  = 1, then select the departure field of the first row and arrival value of the next row. So the correspondence data in 'at_dept' and 'at_arr' should also match correctly with the PK. My PK is s.id as segmentIdPk.  Please refer to the screenshot attached. The text in yellow is what I am looking for and the records in the left are fetch using the following query:-

```
`Select s.id as segmentIdPk,  s.offer_id, 
s.itenid as d_itenid, s.departure, s.at_dept,
s.arrival, s.at_arr
from s_flight_offers_segments s 
where quoteid = 1`
```

another way I tried:

```
`Select  d.segmentIdPk, ar.id,  d.d_itenid, ar.itenid, d.offer_id,
d.departure as outerdept, ar.arrival, ar.at_arr 
from
(
Select s.id as segmentIdPk,  s.offer_id, 
s.itenid as d_itenid, s.departure, s.at_dept,
s.arrival, s.at_arr
from s_flight_offers_segments s 
where quoteid = 1
  
order by s.id ASC 
)
as d  
Left Join s_flight_offers_segments ar on ar.itenid = d.d_itenid`
```

The following code I tried as well using more columns:

```
Select  depart.*, sega.id as segPKA, sega.offer_id, sega.arrival as arrCity, sega.iataCode_arr, sega.at_arr, 
duration as inbound, sega.operating_code as carrierArrival, sega.stops as arr_stops
From 
(
Select    seg.id as segPK,seg.offer_id as oid,  seg.departure as departCity, seg.iataCode_dept, seg.at_dept,
seg.segmentId, seg.itenid , seg.stops,  duration as outbound,
seg.operating_code as carrierDeparture, seg.carrierCode
from 
s_flight_offers_segments seg   
where seg.quoteid  =   1
and
seg.id in (Select MIN(id) from s_flight_offers_segments group by itenid) 
) as depart
Left Join s_flight_offers_segments sega on sega.itenid = depart.itenid
where sega.quoteid  =  1
and
sega.id in (Select MAX(id) from s_flight_offers_segments group by itenid)  



INSERT INTO Offer
  (id, name,   quoteid, resource)
VALUES
  (1, 'KP',   '1', 399),
  (2, 'MK',   '1', 244),
  (3, 'VM',   '1', 555),
  (4, 'KV',   '1', 300),
  (5, 'AJ',   '1', 200),
  (6, 'JG',   '1', 500),
  (7, 'TS',   '1', 600),
  (8, 'KB',   '1', 700)
;


INSERT INTO Itenary
  (id, offerid, quoteId)
VALUES
  (1,  '1',  '1'),
  (2,  '1',  '1'),
  (5,  '2',  '1'),
  (3,  '2',  '1'),
  (4,  '3',  '2'),
  (6,  '3',  '2'),
  (7,  '4',  '2'),
  (8,  '4',  '2')
;




INSERT INTO Segment
  (id, quoteId, offerId, departure, arrival, dept_time, arr_time)
VALUES
  (1,  '1',  '1', 'MEL', 'CMB', '2023-08-01 16:10:00', '2023-08-02 11:30:00' ),
  (2,  '1',  '1', 'CMB', 'BOM', '2023-08-02 14:35:00', '2023-08-02 20:10:00' ),
  (3,  '1',  '2', 'MEL', 'CMB', '2023-10-01 09:25:00', '2023-10-01 12:30:00' ),
  (4,  '1',  '2', 'CMB', 'BOM', '2023-10-01 23:40:00', '2023-10-02 02:15:00' ),
  
  
  (5,  '1',  '3', 'MEL', 'CMB', '2023-08-01 11:00:00', '2023-08-01 16:30:00' ),
  (6,  '1',  '3', 'CMB', 'BOM', '2023-08-02 09:20:00', '2023-08-02 11:05:00' ),
  (7,  '1',  '4', 'MEL', 'CMB', '2023-10-01 09:25:00', '2023-10-01 11:30:00' ),
  (8,  '1',  '4', 'CMB', 'BOM', '2023-10-01 16:40:00', '2023-10-02 07:15:00' )
```

[image: left the query is fetched and on the right, i want to have the output like this]

I tried breaking the query and into subquery which gave me some output but didnt get any luck with it. I also tried grouping and other few options like where id =  Select MAX and also with MIN on the PK but same, no luck.

Thanks a lot

Comment: fks do not push or pull data you need to join..and please publish data as text not images.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have tried all the approached as mentioned in the description section.

Comment: Exactly what defines what the "next" row is?

Comment: @Bohemian the first row is Col: departure) MEL  and (Col: arrival as ) BOM (i.e. segmentIDPk = 1) and the next row I want is vice-versa. BOM and MEL that has segmentIdPk as 3.

Comment: I have updated my description by adding some dummy data. thanks

Comment: So `segmentIdPk` is greater for the "next" row and at_dept/at_arr are swapped?

Comment: yep, the segmentIdPk is the PK and next row is greater. So basically, if the flight is showing journey from MEL to CMB, CMB to BOM (where CMB is the connecting flight) and the return is BOM to CMB and CMB to MEL but want the data to display as MEL to BOM return BOM to MEL with the correct at_depart and at_ arr

Answer (score 0):

Self-join to the "next" row (defined as `id` is greater and `at_dept` and `at_arr` is reversed):

```
Select
  s1.id as segmentIdPk,
  s1.offer_id, 
  s1.itenid as d_itenid,
  s1.departure,
  s1.at_dept,
  s2.arrival,
  s2.at_arr
from s_flight_offers_segments s1
join s_flight_offers_segments s2
  on s2.quoteid = s1.quoteid
  and s2.at_arr = s1.at_dept
  and s2.at_dept = s1.at_arr
  and s2.id > s1.id
where s1.quoteid = 1
```

Not sure which columns of each row you want returned. Edit the source table in the query to suit, or select them all and give them different aliases.

Comment: hi, it didnt work. tried few ways but no luck.

Comment: @KunalParekh have you tried the most recent version (it changed a few times as you posted more comments). Also what exactly do you mean "didn't work"? Wrong data? Error? If wrong data,?how was it wrong?

Comment: just imagine, searching for flights from Melbourne to Bombay (as offerid 1), when u click search, it generates a id (quoteid). The option u may get is MEL to Colombo (segmentid 1, itenary 1 and offerid 1) and Colombo to BOM (segmentid 2, itenary 1 and offerid 1) 1. The return flight is from BOM to CMB (segmentid 3, itenary 2 and offerid 1) and from CMB to MEL as (segmentid 4, itenary 2 and offerid 1).  So the each segments are 1 2 3 and 4.  Data i want is only Segment id 1 showing Mel  and arrival as BOM AND NOT CMB and iten2 as BOM and MELAND NOT CMB (i.e. connecting flight CMB)

Comment: when i run the entire query, it returns no data. I changed few 'AND' statements  but then it shows me departure as DEL or CMB or HKG

Comment: if we add GROUP BY d_itenid is shows some accuracy but i will check them in the database each line and will let you know soon.

Comment: @KunalParekh please create the schema and sample inserted data in an online DB playground like https://dbfiddle.uk/ and post the link to it plus the expected output.